# How to remove the product price for the Payment page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3, order-summary, checkout-summary

Only i need to show the number of quantity items in the order summary section in payment page.

if any one know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure. since i'm new to magento.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Payment page order summary section screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override `subtotal.html` file in your theme under :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal.html

and remove or comment whole code of `subtotal.html` file

run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean && php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you Naresh. its working fine.

Comment: if you know the answer pls answer this question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297552/how-to-remove-payment-method-step-in-checkout-process-in-magento-2-3-2