# How to remove the product price and subtotal amount in the shopping cart page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

Only i need to show the number of quantity items in the shopping cart page.

if any one know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure. since i'm new to magento.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

shopping cart page screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override `form.phtml` file in your theme under :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

and comment the `Price` and `Subtotal's` **th** tag :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Item') ?></span></th>
        <?php /*<th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= __('Price') ?></span></th> */ ?>
        <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></th>
        <?php /*<th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= __('Subtotal') ?></span></th> */ ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

also you need to override `default.phtml` file in your theme under :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

and comment the `Price` and `Subtotal's` **td** tag :

```
<?php /*
    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
            <span class="pricing msrp">
                <span class="msrp notice"><?= __('See price before order confirmation.') ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?=  ($helpLinkId) ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?=  $helpLinkId ?>","productName": "<?= $product->getName() ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                    <span><?= __("What's this?") ?></span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
            <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
        </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
*/ ?>
```

```
<?php /*
    <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
*/ ?>
```

[image]

Flush the cache and check

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you. its working fine.

Comment: you're wc buddy

Comment: if you know pls answer this question also. 
    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297446/how-to-remove-the-product-price-for-the-payment-page-in-magento-2

Comment: check answer updated. if answer working for you then let me know

Comment: ok. I will try and let you know the feedback.