# How to remove payment method step in checkout process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3, payment-step

I have magento Open Source 2.3.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now. How to remove payment method step in checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

If someone know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure, since i'm new to magento.

Any suggestion welcome in advanced.

Below is the exact representation of the requirement.
[image]